# How to use for loop to create buttons that can be then each configured separately in my command function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created 9 buttons with a loop and want each of them to display "x" when clicked.  However, the command function is not properly executing for each button.

I already tried using lambda... I think the issue might be in the way that I named each Button?

```
def create_buttons(self):

      buttoncounter = 1

      for i in range(9):

              self.temp_string = "b" + str(buttoncounter)

              self.temp_string = Button(self, text = "\n\t\n\t\n\t")

              self.temp_string.grid(row = (20 + i), column = (20))

              self.temp_string.configure(command=partial(self.mark_box, 
              buttoncounter))

              buttoncounter += 1


  def mark_box(self, num):

    turnlist = ["x", "o"]

    self.temp_string = "b" + str(num)

    self.temp_string.configure(text = "x")
```

I want to be able to click a button and have it check itself off, but when I click any of the 9 buttons it only checks off the 9th one.

Answer (score 0):

To access widgets created in a loop we use dictionaries and list to keep a reference to them. Later we can modify them from their references stored inside dictionaries or list.

*Like so..*

```
all_buttons = []
for i in range(9):
    button = Button(root, .... )
    all_buttons.append(button)
```

When we need to get a specific button we can get it by `all_buttons[0]` which will gives us the **instance** of the `Button` first created in the loop.

But, if you want to give your own tag or name to refer each `Button` then use **dictionary** where **key** will be the name and **value** will be the instance to the `Button`.

```
all_buttons = {}
for i in range(9):
    button = Button(root, .... )
    all_buttons.update({ 'Button_%s'%i : button })
```

To refer, we use `all_buttons['Button_0']` gives us the first created `Button`.

---

### Now, How to pass commands to each button in a loop.

I see you're using `partial` from `functools` to pass argument to the function `mark_box`, we can also use `lambda` to get the same results without importing functools. **Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/5771855#5771855) for better understanding.**

Here is a combined example of *how to pass arguments in a loop to the callback function of `Button` using `lambda` and also keep the reference to the `Button`?*

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Click the Button')
label.pack()

def update(text):
    label.config(text="Button %s is clicked"%text)

all_buttons = []
for i in range(9):
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Button %s'%i, command=lambda i=i: update(i) )
    button.pack()
    all_buttons.append(button)

print('\nThis the list containing all the buttons:\n', all_buttons)

root.mainloop()
```